# Invalid class typecast - indy FTPServer DoDataChannelOperation

Tags: linux, delphi, ssl, indy

I am implementing an indy `TIdFTPServer` using ssl in both `Windows 10` and `Linux Red Hat 64-bit`. Everything seems to work fine under `Windows` but there is a problem with the `MLSD` command in `Linux`. The called procedure inside unit `IdFTPServer.pas` is `TIDFTPServer.DoDataChannelOperation` where we have

`LContext.FDataChannel.InitOperation(AConnectMode);`

Inside `InitOperation` this code executes :

```
if FNegotiateTLS then begin
  LIO := FDataChannel.IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase;
  if AConnectMode then begin
    LIO.IsPeer := False;
  end;
  LIO.Passthrough := False;
end;
```

where I receive an `Invalid class typecast` exception for the row :

```
LIO := FDataChannel.IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase;
```

My certificates are self-signed and the `SSLOptions.Method` for the server IOHandler is `sslvTLSv1_2`. (This exception does not happen in windows - only in linux). Any kind of help for this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Check out `FDataChannel.IOHandler.ClassName`

Comment: The only time that `FNegotiateTLS` is set to true is when `FDataChannel.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` returns true. So `FDataChannel.IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` causing an error means either the `IOHandler` is nil/invalid to begin with, or Emb has a typecast bug on Linux. Emb uses ARC on Linux, and there have been some IOHandler-related ARC fixes made in Indy, but I don't know if they all made it into the final Tokyo release. Try installing the latest nightly snapshot of Indy and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for the response. At the moment I have no software update perms but I hope in a couple of days I would be able to try that way and see if the exception still occurs.